# Trying to implement working canvas rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

We have here a canvas rotate working flawlessly: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/191.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var angleInDegrees=0;

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,canvas.width/2-image.width/2,canvas.height/2-image.width/2);
}
image.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";

$("#clockwise").click(function(){ 
    angleInDegrees+=90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});

$("#counterclockwise").click(function(){ 
    angleInDegrees-=90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});

function drawRotated(degrees){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.width/2);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

And here an example on my own domain, still working fine: http://flamencopeko.net/draw_rot3.php. Source: http://flamencopeko.net/draw_rot3.txt.

I'm trying to implement the rotate function on this very simple drawing "app": http://flamencopeko.net/draw.php. Source: http://flamencopeko.net/draw.txt. This I have not been able to achieve.

I've read about making a temp canvas of the drawing. Makes sense. But I have not had any luck as of yet.

Suggestions very welcome.

**EDIT: Rotate, flip, and more have been accomplished. Problem solved.**

Comment: `draw3.txt` gives a 404. Also, where are the buttons on the drawing app?

Comment: Sorry about the 404. Fixed. There are no experimental buttons or anything in draw.php. That is the page that is in use on the site.